# How to prevent VBA code from slowing down?

Tags: excel, vba

Why is this code running slower and slower each time I run it?

It ran flawlessly the first few times I ran it. But after a few days, the code takes longer and longer to run.

The sheet Raw_data has the same info in many rows, but with different dates. The code is supposed to look at the Raw_data sheet and get the latest date and move it to the Data sheet.

Is there perhaps a way to clear the memory? I tried a hard reboot of Windows, but it did not solve the problem.

```
Sub sub_name()

    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim name1, name2

    i = 2
    flag = True

    While flag = True
        'check if the current cell has data in it
        If Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            'if the last row has been reached exit the loop
            flag = False
        End If
    Wend

    i = 2
    j = 2
    flag = True

    name1 = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(2, 1)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 1) = name1
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 2) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 2)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 3) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 3)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 4) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 4)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 5) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 5)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 6) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 6)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 7) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 7)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 8) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 8)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 9) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 9)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 10) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 10)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 11) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 11)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 12) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 12)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 13) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 13)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 14) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 14)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 15) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 15)

    i = 3
    j = 3

    While flag = True
        'check if the current cell has data in it
        If Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            name2 = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 1)
            If name2 <> name1 Then
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 1) = name2
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 2) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 2)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 3) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 3)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 4) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 4)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 5) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 5)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 6) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 6)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 7) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 7)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 8) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 8)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 9) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 9)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 10) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 10)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 11) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 11)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 12) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 12)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 13) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 13)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 14) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 14)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 15) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 15)

                name1 = name2
                j = j + 1
            End If

            i = i + 1
        Else
            'if the last row has been reached exit the loop
            'ensure that the last data point is recorded
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 1) = name1
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 2) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 2)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 3) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 3)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 4) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 4)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 5) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 5)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 6) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 6)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 7) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 7)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 8) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 8)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 9) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 9)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 10) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 10)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 11) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 11)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 12) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 12)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 13) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 13)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 14) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 14)
            Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 15) = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 15)

            flag = False
        End If
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: If a hard reboot didn't fix it, we can rule out clearing the memory as a long-term fix. That's exactly what happened with the hard reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be much more efficient (and shorter) if you copy rows in one operation:

```
Sub sub_name()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim currentName, nextName

    i = 2
    j = 2
    currentName = Chr(0) 'not a real name...
    Do
        nextName = Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 1)
        If nextName <> "" Then
            If nextName <> currentName Then
                currentName = nextName 'set the new name...
                DoCopy j, i
                j = j + 1
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Else
            DoCopy j, i - 1 'copy last row with data (so i-1) then exit
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub

Sub DoCopy(j As Long, i As Long)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 1).Resize(1, 15).Value = _
           Sheets("Raw_Data").Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 15).Value
End Sub
```

If you need more of a speed-up then switch to working with arrays.

Comment: Thanks, that made the calculations a bit faster, and the code is so clean.